# List of all devices in a subnet programatically

Tags: linux, networking

I would like to get the list of all the active IP devices in a network using C.

I will explain my problem with an example.

example: I have 5 devices in a network with the IP ranging from

1. device 10.0.0.2
2. device 10.0.0.3
3. device 10.0.0.4
4. device 10.0.0.5
5. device 10.0.0.6

From my application I would like to get this list. My platform is Linux and I am using C. Currently I am not using any networking libraries. If some libraries provide such utilities I am one to use the same.

Please advice on the same.

Comment: The problem is that IP was never designed for this. Different tools use different methods in different network layers, and some tools use many methods, to try to do this. None of the methods are foolproof, and some configurations (e.g. Private VLANs) will completely stymie such attempts. If your application depends on this, it will fail on some networks. Simply having a firewall enabled on a host which blocks ICMP echos will keep your code from detecting it with pings. Looking at the MAC address table in a switch will get the MAC addresses that the switch currently knows.

Comment: @Ron Maupin I am trying to build a server app which will run on multiple devices in a subnet (Like a home network) with a dedicated Port. I have clients apps running on other devices. The client app must discover the active devices and connect to the server ports. Instead of trying to connect to all 255 IPs possible I would like to get a list of all the active IPs and client can connect to them.

Comment: There is no foolproof way to determine what other addresses are in use. This sounds like a job for multicast. You have interested hosts subscribe to a particular multicast group. Use the correct tool for the job. By the way: there are only two current IPs: IPv4 and IPv6. If you mean IPv4 addresses, there could be a variable number of IPv4 addresses in any subnet, but no subnets have 255 possible addresses. a `/24` subnet has 254, a `/25` subnet has 126, and a `/23` subnet has 510 possible addresses. Shorter mask have more possible hosts. It will always be `((32-<mask length>)^2)-2`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no super fast direct logic for knowing which IP-addresses are online, but there are tricks that can be used.

The most common that does not require anything special is just to trying to connect to each host using TCP, on the service you expect.

Another technique can be do send out ICMP ping first, but not all OS'es answer to ping with default settings etc.

Last technique that can be used (that only works for local networks, not via gateway), is that after you try to send the ping, look at the ARP table. If a valid ARP entry exists, the host is online, even if no ping reply has been received.

Comment: Currently I am trying to connect to each IP but that scan takes too long. The idea "Last technique that can be used (that only works for local networks, not via gateway), is that after you try to send the ping, look at the ARP table. If a valid ARP entry exists, the host is online, even if no ping reply has been received." looks promising. Can you please point me to a sample code

Comment: @PrajoshPremdas, your host will only have entries in its ARP table for other hosts to which it has communicated within a certain time period; the ARP table entries time out. Most of these techniques will not work with IPv6, which has 18,446,744,073,709,551,616 possible addresses per subnet. at a million addresses scanned per second, it will take well over half a billion years to scan the subnet.

Comment: @PrajoshPremdas The connect call can be made async with timeout ( http://developerweb.net/viewtopic.php?id=3196 )
. ICMP ping you can find several examples for online, a random one ( https://www.cs.utah.edu/~swalton/listings/sockets/programs/part4/chap18/myping.c ). The current IPv4 ARP table can be found here: "/proc/net/arp"

Answer (score 0):

You can use nmap (note `/24` for the subnet mask, and `-sn` flags for the quick Ping Scan), as stated in the https://www.howtogeek.com/423709/how-to-see-all-devices-on-your-network-with-nmap-on-linux/

```
sudo nmap -sn 192.168.4.0/24
```

You can also do a broadcast ping but `nmap` gives you much more details:

```
ping 192.168.178.255 -b
```